# Implementing powerpoint transitions/animations using Java

Tags: java, powerpoint, transition

I'm working on a project in Java where I need to display a powerpoint presentation complete with transitions and animations. The Apache POI library provides a nice method of viewing previews of different slides statically, but it seems that any animations or transitions need to be implemented separately which, looking at the library seems to be a fair bit of work.

I've no problem with hard work - but I'm somewhat surprised if this hasn't been done already (frantic Googling however hasn't brought up any results.) Does anyone know of a Java library for powerpoint that handles animations relatively easily?

Comment: How did you do that??? I am facing the similar problem where only transition time is the missing information. Please share if you have implemented the solution

Comment: @dhaval I haven't got around to it yet, it's part of a bigger project and due to the amount of work required to implement things in this way I've put it on the back seat for a while. I haven't however found any alternative solutions to the one listed above, if you know of any then please share!

Comment: unfortunately for me the project time was quite small and so i prepared a slide config to accept the transition timing from a web interface for each slide. As of now its working as the amount of slides are manageable (<30). But will be required to find an alternative solution as the app is supposed to manage presentations having more than 150 slides. I will share if at all I find any solution and hope you also share in case you find/implement anything.

Comment: @dhval rest assured should I find a neat solution (or even write a library to do so) I'll share!

Comment: Hey, did you finally find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @YashCapoor Afraid not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone comes up with that PowerPoint Java library for you, you might want to check out [PowerPoint Object Linking and Embedding](http://www.jinksinc.com/JTMOther/JTMAutomation.shtm) (OLE).

Comment: Thanks, that's useful as a last resort if there really isn't a library out there that does the above!

Comment: Looks like from the lack of comments the library that I'm after really isn't out there. Ah well. Have to do things the hard way once in a while!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [COM4J](https://com4j.java.net/) to have almost all the classes/interface of the namespace [microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) , Its almost like your using it from C#. On the code samples from the download you have the package you need with all the interface/classes implemented for you.
Hope it helps you out :P